# How can I automatically generate a list of rows that are in one table and missing from another in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

In my scenarios I source data from an external system and use then augment that data in excel. The source system periodically updates, so I keep the source data separated and use vlookup to map fields for reference.

Also the source data has new entries,

What I want to do is have some way that excel can generate a list of all the new entries that are not in the working sheet. And do this without copy pasting anything to an external sheet.

Im fairly sure I could do this using power query or some of the new excel features sucha as arrays but would like some pointers.

**Working Table**

| ID | Type (Lkup) | Colour (Lkup) | Augmented Data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID1 | Pet Cat | Blue | likes boxes |
| ID2 | Pet Dog | Green | Chews balls |

**Source Table**

| ID | Type | Colour |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID1 | Pet Cat | Blue |
| ID2 | Pet Dog | Green |
| ID3 | Pet Canary | Yellow |

**Diff Table**

| ID | Type | Colour |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID3 | Pet Canary | Yellow |

So how can I automatically generate the Diff table in excel? Edit: Note that in the example there is only one column after ID in real data there are multiple tables.

Answer (score 1):

### Excel 365/2021

```
=FILTER(range, ISNA(VLOOKUP(source, working, 1, FALSE)))
```

- ISNA populates each row of an array with a `1` if VLOOKUP failed to find the lookup value from `source` in `working` (VLOOKUP would return `#N/A`) or `0` if the VLOOKUP succeeded.
- The `range` is then filtered according to that array of ones and zeros.
- The `range` to filter can include more columns than the `source` but they must have matching row counts.
- formula will not tell you the reverse (value in `working` but not in `source`)
- Formula does not compare the `ID`

```
# range E2:F4        # source (F2:F4)  # working (B2:B3)
{"ID1","Pet Cat";    {"Pet Cat";       {"Pet Cat";
 "ID2","Pet Dog";     "Pet Dog";        "Pet Dog"}
 "ID3","Pet Canary"}  "Pet Canary"}  


=FILTER(range,ISNA(VLOOKUP(F2:F4,working,1,FALSE)))

=FILTER({"ID1","Pet Cat"; "ID2","Pet Dog"; "ID3","Pet Canary"},
   ISNA(VLOOKUP(
      {"Pet Cat"; "Pet Dog"; "Pet Canary"},
      {"Pet Cat"; "Pet Dog"},
      1, FALSE)))

=FILTER({"ID1","Pet Cat"; "ID2","Pet Dog"; "ID3","Pet Canary"},
        {0; 0; 1})

={"ID3","Pet Canary"}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any specific reason to not compare the id?

Comment: `source` and `working` can be `ID` or `Type` it doesn't matter as long as they are both `ID` or both `Type`

Answer (score 1):

I use Power Query to do this all the time.

Have one query to reference your working table, and another to reference the source data. In my case usually in a separate CSV file, downloaded to a known folder and then PQ just gets the data from the latest CSV in the folder where the name has some recognised pattern (eg starts with "Srouce data").

Then use the "Merge" command to create a new table as a join between these tables on the ID column, and select Join type "anti join" (left or right depends on which way round you select the tables). I would do this with Source selected first so it is "on the left" since that is the data you want in the result. Throw away the extra column from the Merge operation. Tidy up any data types, get rid of any unwanted columns, sort as required and load the data to see only the rows that are in source but not in working table.

Format your new table appropriately (white text on dark red fill for headings because it is an exceptions table?). I like to add a conditional count of rows on the working page where it can catch someone's eye to say "There's X rows of new data you need to go look at"

If you need more of a "step by step", let me know. Googling Power Query Anti-join will probably yield good results.

Comment: I think a step-by-step guide will be helpful, I've been doing a bit with power query recently so its straight foward enough to follow, but for those less familiar with power query like I was a week ago step by step would be helpful.